# Insert data from Excel to Database using C#

Tags: .net, sql-server, excel, c#-4.0

Hi all I wanted to inserted data from Excel . I have three columns in Excel Excela , Excelb, Excelc .These values i wanted to insert into table throgh stored procedure Here is my code please correct me

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string Path = @"D:\Angular\SIRStatus.xlsx";
    OleDbConnection connStr = new 
    OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", connStr);
    connStr.Open();
    DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    // I dont now how to proceed after this Below code i tried but it is not working Please help me here with this

    foreach (var PCN in dr)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL ZCTS;Initial Catalog=ReportsDB;user id=sa;Password=Sa@12345");
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert1", con);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCN", PCN);
            con.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
         } 
     }
 }
```

The last line give this error

> No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal to a known managed provider native type

Comment: (a) please finish your code snippet :/ At least balance your braces. (b) explain what the problem is, describe what has gone wrong.

Comment: Hi Firstly thanks for your response . and I have edited what i have written in Visual studio .  i have tried above logic to do that. Yes some errors are there but  I dont no how to write logic to insert excel data to db throgh stored proc. I need to insert 3 columns of excel data into table from stored proc

Comment: Please fix the indentation now, it seems that your `foreach` is no longer in `Main()`? Also, state which line you are getting the error and the full text of the error message in your question please.

Comment: I have edited again :)  at ExecuteNonQuery iam Getting this error : No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal to a known managed provider native type. and i am not sure i have written correct logic  and is the above code syntactically correct ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this Method

```
 public static void SaveFileToDatabase(string filePath)
    {
        String strConnection = "SQL Connection";

        String excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", filePath);

        using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString))
        {

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [A],[B],[C],[D] from [Plan1$]", excelConnection))
            {
                excelConnection.Open();
                using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
                    {

                        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Table in SQL";
                        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Later you go to your button (example) and put this

```
            if (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string directoryPath = OpenFileDialog.FileName;
            Excel.SaveFileToDatabase(directoryPath);
        }
```